# How can I filter out all of the noise when using Logger in Android?

Tags: android, logging

I support a very large Android App which has hundreds of Logger messages throughout the app.  Sometimes it can be very difficult trouble shooting defect because of all of the noise.   I know how to filter but even with an app this size it is difficult not to over filter and to just target specific functionality.

What are some of the best practices for Logging that allows you to filter out the noise when trying to target specific flows of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime ago, I took advantage of the `Log`'s tag parameter. I have created methods in my own log wrapper class and was useful when monitoring the logcat output with filter targeted to a specific class and functionality.

A sample method for logging exception with tag attribute set to classname and methodname could be like below. Then in logcat, you may monitor only Foo class and bar() method by tag filtering like "Foo @ bar".

```
public class DLogger{
    public static void e(Exception e) {
        String tag = e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + " @ " + e.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
        Log.e(tag, e);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion.  Thanks